# Prevent user from pasting images into CKEditor 5

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Our users are copy pasting images into the editor (CKEditor 5), which is something we don't want to support.

The suggested fix for CKEditor 4 does not seem to work in 5.

How can I change the editor to disable this feature?

This is my config:

```
const editorConfig = {
  toolbar: ['heading', 'bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList'],
  removePlugins: ['Image', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageUpload', 'ImageCaption'],
  heading: {
    options: [
      {
        model: 'paragraph',
        title: 'Paragraph',
        class: 'ck-heading_paragraph',
      },
      {
        model: 'heading2',
        view: 'h2',
        title: 'Heading',
        class: 'ck-heading_heading2',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely disable the image feature, this is – make it impossible for images to be inserted/loaded in any way to the editor, then you should remove the `Image`, `ImageToolbar`, `ImageStyle`, 'ImageUpload, and `ImageCaption` plugins from your editor. The easiest way to achieve that is to use [`config.removePlugins`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html#removing-features). You can also check how to [install plugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) cause uninstalling is just the opposite process.

If you want to disallow inserting images, but still keep support for those images which are already present in the content, you need to handle it a bit differently. You'd have to block pasting/dropping them which can be done with the [features exposed by the clipboard integration](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/clipboard.html). You may also want to remove the `ImageUpload` plugin in thi case too. Finally, you probably won't need the `imageUpload` button in the toolbar, so you have to [reconfigure it](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html#toolbar-setup).